# When Pop Up menu is visible, <M-Key> no longer works

Tags: key-bindings

I use `Alt` plus `h`/`j`/`k`/`l`/`w`/`e`/ etc... to escape insert mode and move.
e.g. `<M-h>` to escape insert mode and move left.

However whenever the pop up menu is visible (`pumvisible`), then `<M-h>` inserts a `h` instead of exiting insert mode and moving left.

How can I fix the behaviour so that `<M-h>` when the pop up menu is visible escapes insert mode then executes left.

Note: I don't want to create a separate mapping for every possible alt+command, thats just not practical:
e.g.

```
imap <expr> <M-h>  pumvisible() ? "\<ESC>h" : "\<M-h>"
```

*... for every combination*

Comment: Would programmatically mapping using a VimL function be an acceptable solution?

Comment: Also, could you edit your question so as to show what you are currently using?